# Perl eating line one on -n commandline option flag

Tags: perl

I've started playing around with perl and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with telling `perl` to use a loop if I also provide a loop?

It looks like perl is getting confused with the same open file descriptors but what I don't get is why does it eat the first line?

`perl -ne 'while (<>) { print $_; }'`

Of course in this simple example, I can simply `perl -ne '{print $_}'` to arrive at the same functional logic.

But what I want to know is what is going wrong with the double loop that the first line disappears if yet another `while (<>) { }` gets wrapped?

```
$ perl -ne '{print $_}' hello
hello
hello
world
world
^C

$ perl -ne 'while (<>) { print $_; }' 
hello
world
world
^C
```

Update: According to the answers what seems to be happening is that Perl is waiting on the first loop for STDIN input. Upon receiving input on STDIN, the input is assigned to the internal buffer `$_` and the logic proceeds to the second loop where again it waits for new STDIN input. Upon receiving new STDIN input, it clobbers the STDIN buffer `$_` with the new STDIN input and begins printing.

Comment: You should print() before second while loop, if you don't want to skip first line. `perl -ne 'print; while (<>) { print }'`

Comment: @Сухой27 Thanks that's a workaround for the problem, but I'm trying to figure out why should it be necessary. The line buffer gets eaten by opening the second call. Why is not all data buffered for the STDIN file descriptor outputted? I tried some things like `select 0; $|=1; select 1; $|=1` but the result is the same.

Comment: `'{print $_}'` is incorrect. It should be just `print $_` (or even just `print`). The curly brackets `{ }` create a hash reference in Perl. It's not like in awk. Also, if you want to print the lines, you should use `-p` instead, which is like `-n`, except it also prints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can itself check the code generated by one-liner using `O=Deparse`.

**First:**

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse  -ne 'print $_;' file
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

**Second:**

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'while (<>) { print $_; }' file
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
        print $_;
    }
}
-e syntax OK
```

Now, It is easy to know what is wrong with second case. Outer  while eats the first line of file and it is lost.

Comment: Thanks its useful. I knew that a second loop was being generated but this provides a bit more insight yet still doesn't explain why line one is disappearing. It looks to me that Perl doesn't flush because of internal buffering and due to perhaps a bug it simply dumps the buffered data in this case instead of flushing the buffer.

Comment: @A.Danischewski, See the second code snippet, first in outer while you are doing `$_ = <ARGV>`  means assigning `$_` to first-line of file and without printing it 
you are again doing `$_ = <ARGV>` and now you are printing the line so, previous value of `$_` is overwritten or lost(in this case).

Comment: @A.Danischewski `$foo = 1; $foo = 2; print $foo` <--- why did that not print `1`?

Comment: @AruneshSingh It makes sense if you have additional logic, but in this simple case it seems Perl should be a bit smarter than to wrap the loop and clobber the STDIN buffer. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a question of `perl` being "a bit smarter" - it's doing because you _specifically ask it to_ by setting `-n`.

Comment: You could say that about anything, e.g. that it's what you asked the compiler to do. But in reality compilers and many other languages rearrange code for optimization and sanity reasons. I don't see why Perl would presume that someone wants it to eat the first line and clobber the buffer in this case. If you want to make a language really useful that people want to use and learn, you should probably rip a few pages out of compiler design logic to make sure its fast and has sensical default behavior.

Comment: @A.Danischewski I think you are confused. The `-n` switch is quite sensible, you are just using it wrong. `perl -ne'print $_'` will do what you expect. If you add more code, you can change the default behaviour, which is what you did: You added another readline loop. Heck, if you put `perl -ne'print "NO, I'm not printing any lines!"'` it will not print any lines at all from the input. If you put `perl -ne'die "I'm a little teapot!"'` it will not print anything either. YOU are telling perl to discard the first line by adding that code.

Answer (score 3):

The `-n` flag wraps your code inside a `while (<>) { ... }` construct.

So in your second example, the code that is actually executed is

```
while (<>) # reads a line from STDIN, places it in $_
{
    # you don't do anything with the contents of $_ here

    while (<>) # reads a line from STDIN, places it in $_, overwriting the previous value
    {
        print $_; # prints the contents of $_
    }
}
```

Which means the line that was read by the first `<>` is just lost.

Comment: Just lost? For what reason should it be lost? Why is it not flushed? Furthermore it doesn't make sense, since I when executed the first buffer STDIN has no data, the program is setup to the second while loop by the time it starts to receive data -- yet still dumps line 1?

Comment: The `<>` reads a line, then puts it into `$_`. Then you don't do anything with it, so, yes, it gets discarded (replaced by the next `<>` which overwrites `$_` with the next line). **Nothing is printed unless you specifically ask for it to be** (as you do with the inner `print $_;`).

Comment: @A.Danischewski, expanded a bit the answer so you can see what happens.